# ScalaTest: Printing out tag name when running test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, tags, scalatest

I added some custom tags to ScalaTest.  When I run the tests, how do I tell ScalaTest to print the tag name next to the test?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do that. You could override ScalaTest's lifecycle methods to do it, but I'm not sure that's worth it. I'm curious what your goal is. This is probably better discussed on scalatest-users. If you have time please post on the scalatest-users Google group.

Comment: Thanks.  Goal is quite simple: Beyond standard unit tests, we use a heavy test suite to ensure reliability and look for bugs.  A good test is one likely to reveal a bug.  We categorize tests based on the "attack" they take - how they're trying to find bugs - and use tags for this.  It would be great to print out these tags, though of course agreed not worth overriding methods to do so.